# Where should i implement android audio focus change listener?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-audiomanager

I am a beginner in android development. please let me support 
I was developing android music player app. how to stop, pause audio when a phone call arrived or any notification arrived.
Should I implement audio focus change listener in my main activity or my music service class?
If it is in the main activity where should I write code (on create)?
if it is in service class where should I call and create?
if you find any mistakes in my grammer please ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement OnAudioFocusChangeListener in your service class.